# show_option_none is not working in WordPress Category loops

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want to use show_option_none in Category but its not working, Anybody help please?
Here is my code.

```
$args = array(
  'show_option_none' => esc_html_e( 'Select category', 'text-domain' ),
   'show_count'       => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',                                              
    'selected' => -1,
    'depth' => 1,
    'exclude' => 1,
    'hierarchical' => 1,                                              
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'hide_empty'         => 0, 
    'parent' => 0
    );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$category->cat_ID.'">' . $category->name . '</option>';
}
```

I want to shown "Select category" at first option, But its not working. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Use `wp_dropdown_categories` function instead of `get_categories`, i guess `get_categories` function do not have `show_option_none` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes show_option_none is not working with  get_categories() I just replace function

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
```

And Now its Working fine.